# Modify output from Stdout and redirect

Tags: bash, scripting

I am using John the Ripper, an application that outputs a generated password line by line. I want to make a bash script that takes the output of each line and apply "md5sum" to it and print it out.

For example:

```
$ ./john --wordlist=password.lst -rules:Single
12346
fdgh
sdfdfj
test
password1234
...
```

and so on... (really fast)

I want to take each line and apply md5sum to each line.

```
$ md5sum <<< "12346"
f447b20a7fcbf53a5d5be013ea0b15af   -
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
command | while IFS= read -r l; do md5sum <<<"$l"; done
```

or simpler with xargs (or not simpler):

```
command | xargs -n1 sh -c 'md5sum <<<"$1"' --
```

where `command` is your `./john --wordlist=password.lst -rules:Single` command.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ; )